# IIS Express: Cannot bind url with subdomain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-express

I tried to bind a url with subdomain into my application:

```
xyz.localhost:44310
```

Every time I change my `applicationhost.config`, I cannot run my debugger from `Visual Studio 2019`.

There error is:

> Unable to connect to web server "IIS Express"

I have to delete the `applicationhost.config` to be able to run it again, but the bindings will be reverted to default.

This is my binding:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8130:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44310:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44310:xyz.localhost" />
```

The default binding is:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8130:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44310:localhost" />
```

I want to add `xyz.localhost:44310` binding. Also I want to use `*` wildcard like `*.localhost:44310`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I have to add both `http` and `https`:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8130:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8130:xyz.localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44310:localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44310:xyz.localhost" />
```

Then it works